# Stripe Refunds Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe Python library version 1.23.0 with Python 2.7. When I try to process a refund using the following code

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = <my_api_key>
refund = stripe.Refund.create(
        charge=payment_id.stripe_id
    )
```

I get an error that

> 'module' object has no attribute Refund

I have checked the init file and indeed Refund hasn't been imported.

I checked with stripe support and they said

> The Refund object was added on the 1.25.0 version of our library

I cant find any documentation on how refunds are processed in library version 1.23

Comment: @Anoop's response is correct, you can call the `refund` method on charge objects. That said, you should be able to upgrade to the latest version of the Stripe Python bindings (1.43.0) without any issues: Stripe increments the major version number when backwards-incompatible changes are introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = <my_api_key>
resp = stripe.Charge.retrieve(charge_id)
resp.refund()
```